# How to get video information using the Youtube Go API?

Tags: go, youtube-data-api

I simply want to do something like:

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=${ID}&part=snippet&key=${KEY}"
```

With the Go API to figure out the date of an uploaded video. However after pouring over https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3 and the [reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/), I frustratingly can't figure out how to do this basic task.

I can see [VideoSnippet](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3#VideoSnippet) in the godoc, but I don't know how to discover what call returns that.

Comment: Don't the `PublishedAt` is an uploaded video date? The `Video` struct is returned and there is a `Snippet` field inside contains `VideoSnippet`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/youtube/v3/videos` (to search) with query parameter `part=snippet`. Each returned item will contain a `snippet` object with the publish date.

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/Eemxf1NUP9tlqRv5dvxAjeicTjI\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": [{

            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/tq9JVgQy7-68z3ESgWpT0bHx5BE\"",
            "id": "9bZkp7q19f0",
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2012-07-15T07:46:32.000Z",
                ...
```

Example with curl + jq ❤:

```
$ curl "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=9bZkp7q19f0&key=$KEY" -s | jq -r '.items[0].snippet.publishedAt'
2012-07-15T07:46:32.000Z
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with "google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3" though. I known how to do it with curl.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package for this purpose:

```
package main
import "github.com/89z/mech/youtube"

func main() {
   play, err := youtube.NewPlayer("JsjrIa9E9A8", youtube.Key, youtube.Mweb)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   date := play.Date()
   println(date == "2016-07-18")
}
```

https://github.com/89z/mech